# Does not install to hard drive on an MSI Wind

Tags: 10.10, ubuntu-netbook, installation

I'm running Ubuntu from a pendrive.

When `install to hard drive` is selected from the first screen after booting from the pendrive the process stops before the `partitioning drive` page appears.

I have a MSI WIND with recently restored Windows xp.

Answer (score 1):

Try the [alternative CD](https://encrypted.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBYQFjAA&url=http://www.ubuntu.com/desktop/get-ubuntu/alternative-download&ei=naWkTZ-qMKLm0QHLlM2HCQ&usg=AFQjCNF_jjC-JihhNRVfOjjj4STEyGst7Q&sig2=Dkssfq32WRH3fjUZDWfblw) installer.

More than likely it will work where the live CD/USB does not.